# Automatic git submodule update in Pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

Is there a way in Pycharm to automatically perform  `git submodule update` when doing pull requests ?

I have two repositories. One for the main software, and another for a submodule that is also a part of the main software. The reason that it's in a separate repo is that it's being used by another project.

I know that this command would solve the issue:

```
git pull && git submodule init && git submodule update
```

I tried these commands but no luck

```
git config --global alias.pullall '!git pull && git submodule update --init --recursive'
```

and

```
git config --global alias.pullall '!f(){ git pull "$@" && git submodule update --init --recursive; }; f'
```

Any suggestions please ?